# How do I use cordova firebase.dynamiclinks plugin in Ionic 4?

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to use **Cordova Firebase Dynamiclinks** plugin : https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks#installation in my Ionic 4 App.

There is an **Ionic-native-plugin** usage for this too : `npm install @ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links` and usage :

```
import { FirebaseDynamicLinks } from '@ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links/ngx';

constructor(private firebaseDynamicLinks: FirebaseDynamicLinks) { }

...
this.firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink()
  .subscribe((res: any) => console.log(res), (error:any) => console.log(error));
```

Issue is : I want to use `createDynamicLink(parameters)` method available in **Cordova Firebase Dynamiclinks** plugin but **Ionic-native-plugin** says

> Property 'createDynamicLink' does not exist on type 'FirebaseDynamicLinks'.

Therefore, I need to use **Cordova Firebase Dynamiclinks** directly and I tried doing using it like

```
import { cordova } from '@ionic-native/core';
...
cordova.plugins.firebase.dynamiclinks.createDynamicLink({
    link: "https://google.com"
}).then(function(url) {
    console.log("Dynamic link was created:", url);
});
```

But got error

> Property 'plugins' does not exist on type '(pluginObj: any, methodName: string, config: CordovaOptions, args: IArguments | any[]) => any'.

Also tried removing import

```
cordova.plugins.firebase.dynamiclinks.createDynamicLink({
    link: "https://google.com"
}).then(function(url) {
    console.log("Dynamic link was created:", url);
});
```

And got this

> Property 'firebase' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'.

What is the correct usage of cordova plugins?

**Update**

Ionic-native-plugin now contains all the methods available in Cordova Firebase Dynamiclinks plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is more fitting of a comment, but I don't quite have the reputation for it yet.

Currently, there is a PR open in the `@ionic-team/ionic-native` repo ([here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/pull/3437)). This exposes the extra methods, but until then you can use the original repo [here](https://github.com/hawekotte/ionic-native/tree/update-firebase-dl-methods) to get your desired effect. In order to install the repo you will have to follow the directions in the Developer guide [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md#testing-your-changes). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about opened PR. Also regarding the cordova error I could resolve it by declaring cordova as follows : ```declare var cordova : any;```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you'll be able to proceed as you'd like. You won't be able to access the `FirebaseDynamicLinks` plugin directly through the Cordova object (this is why we need the native wrapper). I'd suggest waiting until the PR gets merged or setting up the PR change locally for your repo.

Comment: Just for more information, are you trying to use angular or react under the hood?

Comment: I am using angular and I can access the ```FirebaseDynamicLinks``` plugin directly through the Cordova object.

Comment: I am not terribly familiar with angular (react guy here), but the docs for the exported `cordova` object are [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/core/decorators/cordova.ts). Looks like it might need to be constructed with some necessary arguments before you can try to access deeper pieces. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an ionic 5 app that uses Firebase Dynamic Links and it works great but it took some effort.  I watched videos to understand how Firebase Dynamic Links work but there is certainly much that is not shown.

To answer the original question you can always [manually create a dynamic link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually?authuser=0) which is what I do in our solution.  We created a dynamic link that would help users onboard (register an account).  Our dynamic link has custom onboardingId which originates from the backend process and the link is presented to the user via SMS text message.

This is in app.component.ts constructor
Here is some code that happens when the user clicks the dynamic link:

```
// Handle the logic here after opening the app (app is already installed) with the Dynamic link
this.firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink().subscribe((res: any) =>  {
  console.log('app was opened with dynamic link');
  console.log(res);
  /*   This only fires on subsequent calls and not on app start 20220208 STR
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); //"{"deepLink":"https://localhost/onboard?onboardingId=8ed634b0-53b7-4a0f-b67e-12c06019982a","clickTimestamp":1643908387670,"minimumAppVersion":0}"
  var dynamicLink = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
  var deepLink = dynamicLink.deepLink;
  console.log(deepLink);
  if (deepLink.indexOf("onboard")>=0){
    this.isOnboarding = true;
  }
  alert("deepLink ="+ deepLink);
  */
}, (error:any) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

I originally thought that Firebase handles all of the magic if the user doesn't have the app installed.   I was wrong!  You MUST also handle the code to pickup the dynamic link after the app is installed.

The code below will read the dynamic link from the clipboard and survives the app install process.    Placed in app.component.ts ngOnInit().

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

  this.firebaseDynamicLinks.getDynamicLink().then((data) => {
    //added 20220208 STR try to help open the deep link if app is just installed
    if (data != null) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      //alert("initializeApp():"+JSON.stringify(data));
      var dynamicLink = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      var deepLink = dynamicLink.deepLink;
      console.log("initializeApp():"+deepLink);
      if (deepLink != "") {
        if (deepLink.indexOf("onboard")>=0){
          this.isOnboarding = true;
          this.deepLinkToOnboard(deepLink);
        }
      }
    }
  });}
```

So to handle dynamic links after you have the Firebase plugin installed, you must have two sections of code; one for handling if the app is already installed and another for handling the dynamic link if the app is not installed.